# Keep receving segmentation fault when using scanf on an array inside a struct

Tags: c

I m kind of new at C and i try to learn data structures by doing exercises. This is the code I've written. I don t understand why it dosen't even enter the for loop.

```
/*  Define a structure to store the name, an array
marks[] which stores the marks of three different
subjects, and a character grade. Write a program
to display the details of the student whose name
is entered by the user.*/ 

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct stud_info
    {
       char name[20];
       int marks [2][5];
       int char_grade;
    };
    
    struct stud_info array[20];
    struct stud_info stud1;
    int i,j;
    printf("Enter name of student:\n");
    scanf("%s",stud1.name);
    printf("Enter student char_grade:\n");
    scanf("%d",stud1.char_grade);
    for( i=0;i<=2;i++)
        for( j=0;j<=5;j++)
        {
            printf("Enter grade for [%d]st subject:\n",i);
            scanf("%d",&stud1.marks[i][j]);
        }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Array bounds overflow: please change to `for( i=0;i<2;i++) for( j=0;j<5;j++)` An array length `n` can be indexed to `n-1`.

Comment: .. but *before* the loops `scanf("%d",stud1.char_grade);` should be `scanf("%d",&stud1.char_grade);` The specifier `%d` needs the *address* of its target in `scanf()` but not in `printf()`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you for the time you took to reply. I ll change these and i belive now it should work!

Comment: Please never say that, it sounds like I wasn't quick enough. Just 'thank you for your time' will do.